# Remove specific characters from a tuple in Python without using for loop?

Tags: python

I have a tuple like this - 
('app(le', 'orange', 'ban(ana')
I want to remove bracket "(" from the words app(le and ban(ana.
I have done it this way:

```
a=("App(le", "M(nago","banana")
b= list(a)
c = []
for x in b:
    x = x.replace("(","")
    c.append(x)
c=tuple(c)
```

This is giving me the desired output. 
But I want to do it without using for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map` & `lambda`

**Ex:**

```
a= ("App(le", "M(nago","banana")
print( tuple(map(lambda x: x.replace("(",""), a)) )
```

**Output:**

```
('Apple', 'Mnago', 'banana')
```

Answer (score 3):

It sound like you want to use list comprehension!

Try `c = tuple(x.replace('(','') for x in b)`

[Here's some documentation on list comprehension!](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: Or just `tuple(x.replace('(', '') for x in b)`

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but it works with NO looping.  While Rakesh and RMonaco's answers are probably better, this eliminates all loops.

```
a = '/n/'.join(a).replace('(','').split('/n/')
```

FYI: I did a quick speed test of Rakesh, RMonaco, and my solutions.  I doubt this will be an issue, but it was a point of interest for me so I will share.  After ten-million iterations (that's right, 10E6) in each solution.  I think at this point it comes down to personal preference...

```
>>> Rakesh:   0:00:09.869150
    RMonaco:  0:00:06.967905
    tnknepp:  0:00:05.097533
>>>
```

So we have a maximum difference of 0.47 microseconds per iteration.